# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlexception

I have the table `user`

```
  id  | userLoggingId | UserID | month | year | loginCount | day |
   1  |     801466    | 640000 |  11   | 2013 |     6      |  1  |
```

To receive the **total number of logins by date** I execute the SQL Query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(concat_ws('/', year, month, day), '%Y/%m/%d') as Date, sum(loginCount) as Logins
FROM user
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(concat_ws('/', year, month, day), '%Y/%m/%d') >=:startDate AND
      DATE_FORMAT(concat_ws('/', year, month, day), '%Y/%m/%d') <:endDate
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

The incoming variable **:startDate** and **:endDate** comes from frontEnd in the format like:

**Sun May 01 00:00:00 EEST 2011, Mon May 02 00:00:00 EEST 2011**

These incoming variables I put in the `List<Object> variable`

Before the Hibernate is trying to execute the select and when the code enters in cycle **for**

```
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setQueryTimeout(Report.TIMEOUT);

        // Set the variables
        int index = 1;
        for (Object var : variables) {
            stmt.setObject(index, var);
            index++;
        }
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
        results = putQueryResultsIntoHashMap(rs, md, maxResults);
```

In the line: `stmt.setObject(index, var)` I obtain the Exception

> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

In what here can be the problem?

Comment: I am not sure, but i think you should use `?` instead of `:startDate` and `:endDate`